# Yeoman 1.0 not webapp generator not found?

Tags: generator, yeoman

I am a newbee in the world of yeoman, grunt etc.. I played with Yeoman pre 1.0 and it worked very well. I upgraded to 1.0 and I am having trouble at the most basic level. Tried to run 'yo webapp' and getting 'You don't seem to have a generator with the name webapp installed.' What am I doing wrong? thanks for your help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, apparently there was a bug in the package I downloaded a few days ago... running

```
npm install --force -g generator-webapp
```

fixed it. ([view solution on github](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1008))

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --force -g generator-webapp`

I don't know why when I execute this,it still didn't work for me.

But when I execute this:

`npm install -g generator-webapp`

Then I fixed it.

In fact,when you use yeoman,you should install some generators first.

And if it comes to this:

> Error webapp
>
> You don't seem to have a generator with the name mocha:app installed.
>   You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and
>   then install them with npm install [name] . To see the 18 registered
>   generators run yo with the `--help` option.

you can still execute:

`npm install -g generator-[name]`

Hope this useful for you.